# Page not found 404 error when trying to serve media files in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-media

I want to display user uploaded images in my template. I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

Using Django 2.2 version. I tried what the documentation says (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/) but couldn't find any other solution after this one failed.

This is from settings.py file.

```py
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

This is from my urls.py file in an app called 'signage'

EDIT 1: I changed my urlpatterns to this. Completely unrelated to solving the problem. I just thought it would look better.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.screens_dashboard, name='screens_dashboard'),
    path('new/', views.add_screen, name='add_screen'),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

This is from my signage/models.py file

```py
picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='screens/')
```

This is from my template

```html
<img class="img-fluid" src="{{ screen.picture.url }}" alt="First slide">
```

EDIT 2: It shows this url when I view the source through the console 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/screens/screen1_51svMYv.png'. So it is supposed the way it is but doesn't show the image.

Comment: What do you see as the image URL when you view source through browser?

Comment: Write `{{ screen.picture.url }}` inside a <p> tag and see is the url is correct?